# How to authenticate username/pass from zappier to my PHP website

Tags: php, zapier

I want to integrate zapier with my php website. in the step of authentication, I put http post request to a php file, but I get username/password params blank.

```
<?php

file_put_contents('auth.txt', "here is my zapier auth data" . implode('->', $_POST));

$username = $_POST["username"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
```

The POST has data in the zapier message response.

[image]